# Industrial Control Voltages 120VAC or 24VDC

Tags: control, automation

Lately I have been designing some industrialized products (Industrial Arduino / RP IO boards) for use in automation environments. I have worked in the automation field briefly when I was younger and all of our control voltages were 120VAC. I see a lot of people using 24VDC now and only a few clients ask for 120VAC compatibility.

Without this sounding like an opinion:

Is the automation and controls industry moving away from 120VAC for the safer and more world friendly 24VDC? Or should I be thorough and continue to support both 120VAC and 24VDC?

Comment: I work in a sensors and control industry for commercial and industrial applications, and low voltage DC seems to be gaining popularity, probably because of how systems and the industries using them are changing, IoT (wireless and mesh platforms) seems to be a driving factor. However, there are always those customers that still use 110-277VAC. Our solution to this, instead of having two SKUs, is to provide a low cost (external) AC-DC converter designed specifically for the product.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, the primary issue I have is my products currently have universal 120V/24V discreet logic inputs, life gets easier in many ways if I can support only 24V, then even bring the minimal voltage down to 5V so some 'hobby' users can also interface 5V sensors along with more traditional IO.

Comment: Okay, yeah that is more complicated than just supporting different supply voltages. Depending on your designs, maybe you could have an add-on or some kind of adapter/daughter board that supports/converts the 120VAC I/O?